# Lista em TextField ou em uma Combobox editavel quando o usuário digitar - JavaFX

Tags: java, java-ee, javafx, java-8

Alguém mais experiente, poderia me informar se o JavaFX tem alguma maneira de fazer uma lista conforme você vai digitando na textfield. Exemplo: Quando você vai digitar seu email do facebook, e você digita a primeira letra e ja aparece o teu email em baixo, exatamente igual, porém com mais opções né.

Se não, com uma combobox editavel como eu posso fazer com que ela altere o valueProperty dela, por que quando o usuário digita não altera, somente quando o usuário aperta enter em cima.

OBS: Sistema DESKTOP, não posso usar nada que precise baixar da internet ou coisas do tipo.

Comment: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2013/08/20/how-to-create-autocomplete-combobox-or-textfield-in-java-fx-2/ Boa sorte

Answer (score 1):

Olá eu tenho algo que pode lhe ajudar.
Você precisa dizer qual é o Tipo que o box irá tratar, pode ser qualquer objeto, String, Double, Pessoa.
Só que a comparação vai ser feita pelo o método toString() do objeto.

```
public class AutoSuggestComboBox<T> extends StackPane {

    private double PREF_HEIGHT = 21.0d;
    private TextField textField;
    private ComboBox<T> comboBox;
    private ObservableList<T> mainList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<T> subList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private SimpleObjectProperty<T> selectedItem = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>();
    private ChangeListener<String> textChangeLister = new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
            boolean flag = false;
            for (T str : mainList) {
                if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(arg2)) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                subList.clear();
                for (T str : mainList) {
                    if (str.toString().toLowerCase().contains(arg2) || str.toString().toUpperCase().contains(arg2)) {
                        subList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                comboBox.show();
            }
        }
    };

    public AutoSuggestComboBox() {
        super();
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        getStylesheets().add("br/com/cacti/util/auto-suggest-combo-box.css");

        // ComboBox declaration
        comboBox = new ComboBox<T>();
        comboBox.setItems(subList);
        comboBox.setPrefHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<T>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> paramObservableValue, T paramT1, T paramT2) {
                if (paramT2 != null) {
                    textField.setText(paramT2.toString());
                    selectedItem.set(paramT2);
                }
            }
        });
        comboBox.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> paramObservableValue, Boolean paramT1,
                    Boolean show) {
                if (show) {
                    for (T str : subList) {
                        if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(textField.getText())) {
                            comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(str);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    subList.clear();
                    subList.addAll(mainList);
                }
            }
        });

        // TextField declaration (for auto suggest)
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.setFocusTraversable(false);
        textField.getStyleClass().add("autoSuggest");
        textField.maxHeightProperty().bind(comboBox.heightProperty());
        textField.maxWidthProperty().bind(comboBox.widthProperty().subtract(18));
        textField.textProperty().addListener(textChangeLister);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> paramObservableValue, Boolean paramT1,
                    Boolean focused) {
                if (focused) {
                    comboBox.getStyleClass().add("combo-focused");
                } else {
                    comboBox.getStyleClass().remove("combo-focused");
                }
            }
        });

        // Adding the children in the stack pane.
        getChildren().addAll(comboBox, textField);
    }

    /**
     * Method to return the ComboBox<T>
     * 
     * @return ComboBox
     */
    public ComboBox<T> getComboBox() {
        return this.comboBox;
    }

    /**
     * Method to return the selectedItem of the comboBox.
     * 
     * @return SimpleObjectProperty<T>
     */
    public SimpleObjectProperty<T> selectedItemProperty() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    /**
     * Method to set the items to the combo box as well as take backup of the
     * list. NOTE: To get the actual results of AutoSuggest, Setting of items to
     * the combo box should happen through this method only.
     * 
     * @param items
     *            ObservableList<T>
     */
    public void setItemsToCombo(ObservableList<T> items) {
        mainList.clear();
        subList.clear();
        mainList.addAll(items);
        subList.addAll(items);
    }

    public void setPromptText(String value){
        textField.setPromptText(value);
    }

    public void setValue(T valor){
        if(valor != null){
            selectedItem.set(valor);
            textField.setText(valor.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

E o css auto-suggest-combo-box.css

```
.autoSuggest, .autoSuggest:focused{
        -fx-padding: 0 5 0 5;
        -fx-background-color: -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1;
    -fx-background-radius:3 0 0 3;
}

.combo-focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 6.4, 4, 5, 3;
    -fx-background-insets: -1.4, 0, 1, 2;
}
```